# How does one install Bitcoin Core on a CentOs server?

Tags: installation, centos

I would like to install Bitcoin Core on a CentOs server.
Where can I find instructions, or what are the exact steps to install Bitcoin Core on a CentOs Server?

Answer (score 3):

There is an rpm family for Centos 7 - and remember you will need at least 300 GB of hard drive space to keep it running for a while - and the blockchain itself is approaching 200 GB alone.  it hits the cPU cores pretty hard, and then you will need good security because it will invite every hacker in the world to break in.  Within 12 hours of putting ours up - we had 59,000 attempted unauthorized log ins

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and tested Makefile for local-user environment for compiling and installing Bitcoin Core UASF patch (https://github.com/UASF/bitcoin)

https://github.com/Perlover/bitcoin-uasf-makefile

Please README.txt there (why i did it)

Best regards, Perlover :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and tested Makefile for local-user environment for compiling and installing Bitcoin Core UASF patch (https://github.com/UASF/bitcoin) at CentOS

https://github.com/Perlover/bitcoin-uasf-makefile

Best regards, Perlover :)

Comment: duplicated to first answer by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Enable snaps on CentOS and install bitcoin-core

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

Either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly.

after :

```
sudo snap install bitcoin-core
```

Comment: fails for me: [root@426x bin]# sudo snap install bitcoin-core
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-squashfs-590648466: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory, CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009